# Service NO funciona correctamente

Tags: android

No puedo hacer que un servicio funciona correctamente. He creado un Servicio para captar las coordenadas GPS y que las grabe en firebase en una B.D.
Esta es la API que utilizo:

```
compileSdkVersion 30 
minSdkVersion 26
```

Este es el Servicio:

```
package com.valhondo.delgado.procesionesgps;

import ...

public class ServiciosGPS extends Service {
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;

    FirebaseFirestore mfirestorgps;

    String gmidpasosservicios, erroeservicio;

    private LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            if ( locationResult == null ) {
                return;
            }
            for ( Location location: locationResult.getLocations() ) {
                // grabo la localizacion en la Base de Datos

                Map<String, Object> mapgps = new HashMap<>();
                mapgps.put( "longuitud", location.getLongitude());
                mapgps.put( "latitud", location.getLatitude());
                mfirestorgps.collection( "GPS" ).document( gmidpasosservicios ).update( mapgps );

            }
        }
    };

    public ServiciosGPS() { }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient( this );
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval( 1000 );
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval( 500 );
        locationRequest.setPriority( LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY );

        mfirestorgps = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int  flags, int startId) {

        if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra("paseidpasos")) {
           gmidpasosservicios = intent.getStringExtra("paseidpasos");
        }
        LocationSettingsRequest locationSettingsRequest = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest( locationRequest ).build();
        SettingsClient settingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient( ServiciosGPS.this );
        Task<LocationSettingsResponse> locationSettingsResponseTask = settingsClient.checkLocationSettings( locationSettingsRequest );
        locationSettingsResponseTask.addOnSuccessListener( new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
                // Coordenadas satifactorfias
                startlocalizacongps();
            }
        } );
        locationSettingsResponseTask.addOnFailureListener( new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                // Si falla las coordenadas
                erroeservicio = "No hace nada solo si da error. pasa de el";
            }
        } );
        return  START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates( locationCallback );
        //waitALittle();
        stopSelf();
    }

    private void waitALittle() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void startlocalizacongps() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates( locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper() );
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Este es el Androidmanifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
......
  <service
            android:name=".ServiciosGPS"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:foregroundServiceType="location"/>
```

Y aqui esta el quick de lam cuestion lo que empieza a preocuparme:

1.- Si al Servicio lom llamo Asi:

```
Intent intentpasos = new Intent(this, ServiciosGPS.class );
intentpasos.putExtra("paseidpasos", gmidpasos);
this.startService( intentpasos );
```

El servicio funciona, veo que se van grabando las coordenadas en la B.D., pero al pasar a segundo plano el servicio se detiene si vuelves a primer plano sigue funcionando bien. Esto es lo que me da:

```
I/System.out: Provider contains=> gps,network
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 31072
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 3744793
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x7aeb76e000,api=1)
I/GED: ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 31, oppidx_max 31, oppidx_min 0
V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4, Parent =  android.view.ViewRootImpl@62a38db, this = DecorView@ae0268c[PasosActivity]
D/FA: Application going to the background
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 3762960
V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@62a38db, this = DecorView@ae0268c[PasosActivity]
D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x7aeb76e000,api=1)
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
D/Surface: Surface::setBufferCount(this=0x7aeb76e000,bufferCount=3)
D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x7aeb76e000)
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: com.valhondo.delgado.procesionesgps activity: com.valhondo.delgado.procesionesgps.Pasos.PasosActivity@b5cda41
I/chatty: uid=10405(com.valhondo.delgado.procesionesgps) identical 2 lines
D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: com.valhondo.delgado.procesionesgps activity: com.valhondo.delgado.procesionesgps.Pasos.PasosActivity@b5cda41
D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: com.valhondo.delgado.procesionesgps activity: com.valhondo.delgado.procesionesgps.Pasos.PasosActivity@b5cda41
I/chatty: uid=10405(com.valhondo.delgado.procesionesgps) identical 4 lines
D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: com.valhondo.delgado.procesionesgps activity: com.valhondo.delgado.procesionesgps.Pasos.PasosActivity@b5cda41
D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: com.valhondo.delgado.procesionesgps activity: com.valhondo.delgado.procesionesgps.Pasos.PasosActivity@b5cda41
I/chatty: uid=10405(com.valhondo.delgado.procesionesgps) identical 8 lines
D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: com.valhondo.delgado.procesionesgps activity: com.valhondo.delgado.procesionesgps.Pasos.PasosActivity@b5cda41
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

2 Si pòr el contrario lo llamo asi:

```
Intent intentpasos = new Intent(this, ServiciosGPS.class );
intentpasos.putExtra("paseidpasos", gmidpasos);
this.startForegroundService(intentpasos);
```

Empieza bien incluido en segundom plano pero a los 5 segundo se sale y me da este error:

```
I/System.out: Provider contains=> gps,network
I/.procesionesgp: Thread[7,tid=15595,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x7b53ac1400,peer=0x14a802f0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
I/.procesionesgp: Wrote stack traces to tombstoned
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.valhondo.delgado.procesionesgps, PID: 15582
    android.app.RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground(): ServiceRecord{9aa65e2 u0 com.valhondo.delgado.procesionesgps/.ServiciosGPS}
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2000)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7561)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:995)
```

He leido en la documentacion que al utilizar startForegroundService hay que utilizar esta funcion startForeground() dentro del Servicio, sino a los 5 segundo te da este error: "Si una aplicación orientada al nivel de API 28 o versiones posteriores intenta crear un servicio en primer plano sin solicitar FOREGROUND_SERVICE, se genera una SecurityException en el sistema"

POR FAVOR, me podeis dar una solucion para que pueda crear un servicio que pueda pedir las coordenadas GPS y grabarlas en una B.D. y que pueda utilizarse en SEGUNDO PLANO.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Veo que tienes definido el permiso:

```
<manifest ...>
     ...
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
     ...
     <application ...>
     ...
</manifest>
```

Pero tu servicio lo inicias de esta forma:

```
Intent intentpasos = new Intent(this, ServiciosGPS.class );
intentpasos.putExtra("paseidpasos", gmidpasos);
this.startService( intentpasos );
```

debes usar `startForegroundService()` :

```
Intent intentpasos = new Intent(this, ServiciosGPS.class );
intentpasos.putExtra("paseidpasos", gmidpasos);
this.startForegroundService( intentpasos );
```

Revisa [Límites de ejecución en segundo plano](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background)

> Antes de Android 8.0, el modo usual de crear un servicio en primer
> plano consistía en crear un servicio en segundo plano y luego hacer
> que pasara a funcionar en primer plano. Con Android 8.0, existe una
> complicación: el sistema no permite que una app que está en segundo
> plano cree un servicio en ese plano. Por esta razón, en Androidִ 8.0
> se presenta el nuevo método [startForegroundService()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#startForegroundService(android.content.Intent)) para iniciar un
> servicio nuevo en primer plano. Una vez que el sistema crea el
> servicio, la app tiene cinco segundos para llamar al método
> [startForeground()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) de ese servicio a fin de mostrar la notificación
> visible para el usuario del nuevo servicio. Si la app no llama a
> [startForeground()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) en ese plazo, el sistema detiene el servicio y
> declara un estado ANR para esta.

Comment: OK, muchas gracias, pero como se utilizar startForeground() porque lo he intentado y nada de nada,